# JDO3.x with DataNucleus3.x caching: how to set expirationTime and chack consistancy

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

searching good documentation for the caching in datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-m3.
its really hard to find some up to date information....

i tried this :

```
        DataStoreCache cache = PMF.getDataStoreCache();
        cache.pinAll(false, MyClazz.class);
        JDODataStoreCache jdoCache = (org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDODataStoreCache) cache;
        final Level2Cache l2 = jdoCache.getLevel2Cache();
```

should i use an external cache like javax.cache and how to do that?

questions:

- how i can prove that the pm's are using the cache?
- how to set the expirationTime for objects in the cache?
- how to set that the pm's are using the cache only for reading and not for
  writing?
- am i getting an exception if the cache is used in an
  write/update-transaction but is not consistent with the datastore?
- is the method "checkConsistency" of the PM throwing an exception
  if the cache is not up to date and how much "costs" this method?

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you think its really hard to find info. You presumably went to the GAE docs and they say go to the appropriate DataNucleus docs for the version being used. You say you're using some 3.1 version (*why use a milestone when there are many releases after that?* Using 3.1.3 makes much more sense than something that is not a full release), so you get to http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/index.html  and then simply select "JDO API" -> "PMF" -> "L2 Cache" -> "JCache"

Not sure how we can get it any more logically structured